# Не запускается файл docker-compose

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker-compose

Я только начал изучать докер и пока что получается не очень. Столкнулся с тем, что не выполняется файл docker-compose.yaml. Я понимаю, что это слишком узкий вопрос и вряд ли мне здесь помогут разобраться, но я не нашел решения проблемы в гугле, может, вы сможете посоветовать, где искать?
Ошибка вот такая:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.dbus'

[5094] Failed to execute script docker-compose

В директории находятся два докерфайла, файл docker-compose и питоновский скрипт. Питоновский скрипт исполняемый. Может, при запуске docker-compose надо дополнительно указывать права или делать что-то вроде chmod +x?

Вот полный вывод
$docker-compose build

```
db uses an image, skipping
Building worker0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 71, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 127, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 282, in build
  File "compose/project.py", line 373, in build
  File "compose/service.py", line 1047, in build
  File "site-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 154, in build
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 30, in tar
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 82, in exclude_paths
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 124, in walk
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 124, in <genexpr>
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 100, in walk
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.dbus'
[6193] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

Comment: а что такое /home/.dbus?

Comment: вообще проблема в том, что нет прав доступа на файл /home/.dbus, можно повесить доп права chmod 775 /home/.dbus

Comment: странный это файл '/home/.dbus'. Обычно он выглядит как /home/Leo/.dbus' К этому файлу похоже пытается обратится питоновский скрипт. Но что мы будем гадать, может лучше хоть немного показать содержимое файлов?